# Android Manage view sizes on different screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make my view Responsive, look at following images.

[image]

[image]

1st Image is what it should ideally look. 
But when I change the screen size, it changes the size and alignment. I want fixed size views over all screens.

Comment: You can create different screen layout see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Comment: You need to learn the Android basics at least. Make sure you understand how Android xml layouts works, what is dp, how can you set the views and so on. It won't happen in 1 day, you need to learn it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow Step by Step approach .

> Android runs on a variety of devices that offer different screen sizes
>   and densities. For applications, the Android system provides a
>   consistent development environment across devices and handles most of
>   the work to adjust each application's user interface to the screen on
>   which it is displayed.

Read [**`Supporting Multiple Screens`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) .

> To optimize your user experience on different screen sizes, you should
>   create a unique layout XML file for each screen size you want to
>   support.

- Read official guideline about [Supporting Different Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) .
- Read [Build a Responsive UI](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) .

Comment: Thank You! I have gone thought some of the documentation. Isnt there any library I can use to make it responsive? Like for Web application there is bootstrap ?

Comment: @AkashPatil AFAIK, `Isnt there any library I can use to make it responsive?` NO

Comment: It is helpful, need some more resource, as I feel it is a bit complicated for a novice programmer like me.

Comment: @AkashPatil download google sample https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: Okay Thanks alot mate :D